# Find a sequence of whole numbers $n _ { 1 } , n _ { 2 } , \ldots$ such that $n _ { i - 1 } | n _ { i }$ for all $i \geq 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

> **Problem :** Find a sequence of whole numbers $n _ { 1 } , n _ { 2 } , \ldots$ such that $n _ { i - 1 } | n _ { i }$ for all $i \geq 2$ and for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists $i$ such that $k | n _ { i }$.

The subject of the exercice is "the splitting field of $\mathbb{F}_p$", with $p$ a prime. But this first question doesn't seem to relate (yet) to rings and fields theory.

This question makes me think of the proof of the the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups with invariant factors.

Comment: What have you tried? For instance, one famous sequence in particular stands out to me as almost _made_ for this purpose. Try constructing such a sequence yourself, and maybe you can figure out which one I'm talking about.

Comment: @arthur the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: The Fibonacci sequence has, somewhere close to the beginning, a $2$ and then a $3$. Do we have $2\mid 3$?

Comment: @Arthur Sorry that was a dumb and quick answer, you said "famous sequence" and I directly thought about this. I'm gonna look into that.

Comment: De **facto**... you can just multiply by increasing sequence of numbers.

Comment: @Arthur Got it, is it the factorial numbers?

Comment: They will work wonderfully. You do have to check this yourself, though. You shouldn't trust strangers on the internet, after all :)

Comment: @Arthur Sure, thank you for your help. I should have thought a little bit more about this before posting on StackExchange. Have a nice day!

Comment: I dare guess it is about the algebraic closure of $\Bbb{F}_p$. The condition $n_{i-1}\mid n_i$ tells us that $\Bbb{F}_{p^{n_{i-1}}}\subset\Bbb{F}_{p^{n_{i}}}$ when we can form the nested union $K=\bigcup_i\Bbb{F}_{p^{n_{i}}}$. The condition $k\mid n_i$ tells us that $\Bbb{F}_{p^k}\subset K$. So $K$ contains all the finite fields of characteristic $p$ and is thus algebraically closed.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You're exactly right. The goal of the exercise was to show that $\overline { \mathbb { F } } _ { p }= \bigcup _ { i } \mathbb { F } _ { p ^ { n _ { i } } }$ as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about
$n_i = i!$?

(Is this enough characters?)